# Prove that the set of edges of a Delaunay triangulation of $P$ contains an EMST (Euclidean minimum spanning tree) for $P$

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, triangulation

I was studying computational geometry on my own from "Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications" - by Mark de Berg. In chapter 9, i.e. Delaunay Triangulation, there is an exercise that reads:

> A Euclidean minimum spanning tree (EMST) of a set P of points in the
> plane is a tree of minimum total edge length connecting all the
> points. EMST’s are interesting in applications where we want to
> connect sites in a planar environment by communication lines (local
> area networks), roads, railroads, or the like.

1. Prove that the set of edges of a Delaunay triangulation of $P$ contains
   an EMST for $P$.
2. Use this result to give an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm to compute an EMST
   for $P$.

How do I go about approaching this problem? Any answer/resources that could give more insight into this would be helpful.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree#Subtree_of_Delaunay_triangulation) answers the first part. The second part follows from the first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered on Wikipedia.

Comment: Sure, I'll check wikipedia, but could you add a few more resources ? or let people add some thing else.

Comment: Wikipedia contains a complete proof sketch. The Wikipedia article on Delaunay triangulations contains a pointer to the literature (a monograph with, presumably, a complete proof). The purpose of this site is not to duplicate existing literature, but to fill gaps in the literature.

Comment: Here are lecture notes with a complete proof: https://toodle.cs.huji.ac.il/cs14/file.php/67599/CG-lecture8-DT.pdf. You can surely find many more by searching for keywords such as "EMST" and "Delaunay".